# "TypeError: children.props is undefined" error when adding <div> to NextJS component return statement

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, next.js

React/NextJS newbie issue any help is much appreciated. I have a header component built on React/NextJS and Material. This return statement works like a charm.

```
return (
    <header>
      <HideOnScroll {...props}>     
        <AppBar className={header}>
          {mobileView ? displayMobile() : displayDesktop()}
        </AppBar>
      </HideOnScroll>
    </header>
  );
```

But as soon as I add a basic div, as shown below, I get "TypeError: children.props is undefined". I'm just trying to add a full width div with a height of 10px to the top of the header for some trim but can't even get a div to render. I've tried adding {...props} to the div but still no luck.

```
return (
    <header>
      <HideOnScroll {...props}>   
        <div>test</div>     
        <AppBar className={header}>
          {mobileView ? displayMobile() : displayDesktop()}
        </AppBar>
      </HideOnScroll>
    </header>
  );
```

**Full source code below:**

```
import {
  AppBar,
  Toolbar,
  Typography,
  makeStyles,
  Button,
  IconButton,
  Drawer,
  Link,
  MenuItem,
  Slide,
  useScrollTrigger
} from "@material-ui/core";
import MenuIcon from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import NextLink from "next/link";


const headersData = [
  {
    label: "Home",
    href: "/",
  },
  {
    label: "Blog",
    href: "/blog/ryan-test",
  },
];

const useStyles = makeStyles(() => ({
  header: {
    backgroundColor: "#400CCC",
    paddingRight: "79px",
    paddingLeft: "118px",
    "@media (max-width: 900px)": {
      paddingLeft: 0,
    },
  },
  logo: {
    fontFamily: "Work Sans, sans-serif",
    fontWeight: 600,
    color: "#FFFEFE",
    textAlign: "left",
  },
  menuButton: {
    fontFamily: "Open Sans, sans-serif",
    fontWeight: 700,
    size: "18px",
    marginLeft: "38px",
  },
  toolbar: {
    display: "flex",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
  },
  drawerContainer: {
    padding: "20px 30px",
  },
  topTrim: {
    height: "10px",
    width: "100%",
    backgroundColor: "red",
  }
}));



export default function Header(props) {
  const { header, logo, menuButton, toolbar, drawerContainer, topTrim } = useStyles();

  const [state, setState] = useState({
    mobileView: false,
    drawerOpen: false,
  });

  const { mobileView, drawerOpen } = state;

  const TopTrim = () => {
    return <div>Hello</div>;
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    const setResponsiveness = () => {
      return window.innerWidth < 900
        ? setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, mobileView: true }))
        : setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, mobileView: false }));
    };

    setResponsiveness();

    window.addEventListener("resize", () => setResponsiveness());
  }, []);

  const HideOnScroll = (props) => {
    const { children } = props;
    const trigger = useScrollTrigger();
    return (
      <Slide appear={false} direction="down" in={!trigger}>             
        {children}
      </Slide>
    );
  }

  const displayDesktop = () => {
    return (     
      <Toolbar className={toolbar}>        
        {femmecubatorLogo}
        <div>{getMenuButtons()}</div>
      </Toolbar>
    );
  };

  const displayMobile = () => {
    const handleDrawerOpen = () =>
      setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, drawerOpen: true }));
    const handleDrawerClose = () =>
      setState((prevState) => ({ ...prevState, drawerOpen: false }));

    return (
      <Toolbar>
        <IconButton
          {...{
            edge: "start",
            color: "inherit",
            "aria-label": "menu",
            "aria-haspopup": "true",
            onClick: handleDrawerOpen
          }}
        >
          <MenuIcon />
        </IconButton>

        <Drawer
          {...{
            anchor: "left",
            open: drawerOpen,
            onClose: handleDrawerClose,
          }}
        >
          <div key="test1" className={drawerContainer}>{getDrawerChoices()}</div>
        </Drawer>

        <div key="test2">{femmecubatorLogo}</div>
      </Toolbar>
    );
  };

  const getDrawerChoices = () => {
    return headersData.map(({ label, href }) => {
      return (
        <NextLink href={href} key={label} passHref>
          <MenuItem>{label}</MenuItem>
        </NextLink>
      );
    });
  };

  const femmecubatorLogo = (
    <Typography variant="h6" component="h1" className={logo}>
      Femmecubator
    </Typography>
  );

  const getMenuButtons = () => {
    return headersData.map(({ label, href }) => {
      return (
        <NextLink href={href} key={label} passHref>
          <Button
            {...{
              key: label,
              color: "inherit",
              to: href,
              className: menuButton,
            }}
          >
            {label}
          </Button>
        </NextLink>
      );
    });
  };

  return (
    <header>
      <HideOnScroll {...props}>   
        <div>test</div>     
        <AppBar className={header}>
          {mobileView ? displayMobile() : displayDesktop()}
        </AppBar>
      </HideOnScroll>
    </header>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Pass it like this :

```
<HideOnScroll {...props}> 
   <>  
      <div>test</div>     
      <AppBar className={header}>
      {mobileView ? displayMobile() : displayDesktop()}
      </AppBar>
   </>
</HideOnScroll>
```

Comment: Thanks @mohit  Seems to work fine until I scroll at which point it returns a different error "Uncaught TypeError: node is null. The above error occurred in the <Transition> component:"

Comment: Use the div instead the react fragment. <HideOnScroll {...props}> <div>{..rest}</div></HideOnScroll>

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately, I ended up in moving the div to inside of the AppBar. I now have to adjust AppBar padding and spacing of anything living inside of AppBar to compensate for the div also living there but it is working.

```
return (
    <header>
      <HideOnScroll {...props}>
        <AppBar className={header}>
          <div className={topTrim}>This is a test</div>
          {mobileView ? displayMobile() : displayDesktop()}
        </AppBar>
      </HideOnScroll>
    </header>
  );
```